# How to relate a record in an SQL database to another record without a list?

Tags: python, mysql, relational-database

Because it is bad practice to create a column that stores a list in SQL , I am confused on how I should relate usernames in my users table as followers of other users. It seems a bit overkill to create a table for each user as well , so how can I do this? My database model at the time is the following

```
TABLE - USERS
id - (int) auto-increment and primary key
ip - (varchar) records the users ip on message , will be used to recognize aliases
su - (int) used to assign permissions
username - (varchar)
```

Comment: Maybe you need a relationship table. Save the follow data: Id1 Id2

Comment: I'm confused by the ld1 and 2 , could you explain? Users could be following multiple users and could block users from following them , so this complication is messing up my idea of a database model

Comment: see first answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Yang Yu in comment, you need to create new table

Table `followers` with two columns

- `userIdToFollow` integer
- `userIdFollower` integer

You can make both as one composite primary key `(userIdToFollow, userIdFollower)`. And another unique index as `(userIdFollower, userIdToFollow)`.

To find list of followers of a user with username 'abc'

```
SELECT users.id FROM users
INNER JOIN followers
ON users.id = followers.userIdFollower
WHERE followers.userIdToFollow = users.id AND 
users.username = 'abc'
```

To find the list of users that 'abc' is following you just switch it

```
SELECT users.id FROM users
INNER JOIN followers
ON users.id = followers.userIdToFollow
WHERE followers.userIdFollower = users.id AND 
users.username = 'abc'
```

Comment: I SEE , you make the relationships separate records themselves.